# How to assign 2 taxonomy vocabularies in a single field for a node?

Tags: 7, entities, taxonomy-terms

I have a node. I want to manage fields of this node in the Admin, so I can have a field which is of type Term reference and which uses two or more taxonomy vocabularies. So I can make combinations of 2 vocabularies in the field.

Let's say I have vocabularies A and B. I want to have the field "Categories", which gives the option of choosing from vocabularies A and B. Now, in the normal behaviour of Drupal, I must select one and only one vocabulary when creating the field.

Answer (score 1):

Usually is is not good to rely on modules what are not widely used (like Combined Termref), because of worse community support and maitainance.

Consider using [Entity Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) module what can connect any type of entities together. You can use it almost the same way like Term reference field.

There propably will be some differences in configuration, but nothing critical (blocking use-cases), just less straightforward. Internally it will works the same - is saves entity ID of term into "term reference field".

Comment: But can it group 2 taxonomy vocabularies into the single field? Do you have some working example?

Comment: Yes. In Entity Reference field can be configured to target multiple entity bundles (entity bundle = vocabulary in Taxonomy) in one entity type (taxonomy term). I don't have public working example, but I used it many times.

Answer (score 0):

[Combined Termref](https://www.drupal.org/project/combined_termref)

> This module allows you to associate upto 3 vocabularies to a
>   term-reference field. Standard drupal term reference fields allows you
>   to reference terms in a single vocabulary.

I am not already use this module but i think it solve your problems

Comment: I am going to try it.

Comment: Finally I didn't use it because of not Views integration. I have solved the problem in other extremely simple way.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally found the solutions, which is very simple: Field Collection. I can group the taxonomies and other fields. I have checked with a View with exposed filters and works perfectly.

[image: Field Collections]